# HTML list elements top to bottom, then left to right

Tags: html, css

I want to do a list of a bunch of items. The height is fixed. So when the list hits the bottom, I want it to wrap around and start a new column. Is there a way, without knowing the height of each item, to do this in css? That way the overflow will occur horizontally.

Comment: Like example two here? http://www.alistapart.com/articles/multicolumnlists/

Comment: Is your list a literal html list (<ol> or <ur>) or just a bunch of divs with content?

Comment: Exactly like that @mrtsherman. Except it looks like they just count the size of each item's height and divide by the parent's height. Then force wrap. I was looking for something more dynamic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use CSS3 columns.

Here's a fiddle: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fA7ay/2/) and here's the [WC3 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/)

Comment: I didn't think any browsers supported this yet, but I guess Chrome does. Perfect!

Answer (score 2):

I can't think of a way using css to accomplish this but if you're not opposed to jquery, check out this: http://welcome.totheinter.net/columnizer-jquery-plugin/

Comment: Definitely not opposed to jquery

Answer (score 2):

Check this [CSS Trick](http://css-tricks.com/arranging-elements-top-bottom-instead-left-right-float/)

the key is this CSS:

```
    ul {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
```

It will do exactly what you ask.

Answer (score 1):

There is a proposed CSS 3 property for multicolumns (see [Quirksmode.org -- Columns](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/multicolumn.html) for examples using the proprietary properties), but that's not supported in all modern browsers yet.  Even so, I'm not sure the support is as repeatable across the browsers that do support it as one might hope.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you for JavaScript. It is simple and compatible with all browser

If you go for CSS3 then IE (The Useless browser) Will not support it.

I will just give you a hint for javascript

just Calculate Height of your Parent Div

```
   var height = document.getElementById("ParentDiv").style.height;
```

Create Child div with same height and add your Divs inside it new child div.

If height of child div is get exceeds that parent div

Create another child div and continue the process.

This process is hectic but will support to all browser

When jQuery-plugins are Good option but I personally feel that if they can do it you can do it.

All the best

Comment: Hello, can this work using traditional HTML lists instead of divs? @Rajiv

Comment: Yes, You can, instead div, create new list.

Comment: Thanks, please post HTML markup and JS solution with optional JSFiddle or CodePen if you'd like this answer to be accepted.