# How to pack contents in a div to move to the right when content reaches bottom of the div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

Im generating some content with PHP, but after the number of contents is more than 5 the height becomes greater than that of the div, so i don't want it to stack on top of the div, but to move to the right of the div and start from the top. Here's an image.

[image: Stacked Books]

**PHP**

```
echo '<a class="LibSectOpen">
       <span style="display:none" class="SectionName">'.$Section.'</span>
       <div class="LibrarySects"><div class="LibrarySectsHeader">'.$Section.'</div>
       <div class="LibrarySectsShelf">';
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($log2)){ 
          echo '<div class="LibrarySectsShelf_Book" style="background-color:'.$Color.'"
          title="Author: '.$row['bbookauthor'].'">'.$row['bbookname'].'</div>';
        }
echo ' </div>
       </div>
      </a>';
```

As it looks, the philosophy books in the example goes down, and i want it to go to the right and start another column of five books and so on.

Any ideas i can do this with JQuery and CSS?

```
.LibrarySectsHeader {
    border:1px #CCC solid;width:500px; margin:2px; padding:1px; height:18px;border-radius:2px 2px 2px 2px; font-size:10px; color:rgba(0,0,0,1) !important; background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.6); line-height:18px;
                  }
.LibrarySectsShelf {
    border:1px #CCC solid;width:499px; margin:2px; padding:1px; height:129px;border-radius:2px 2px 2px 2px; font-size:10px; background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.2); line-height:18px; background-image:url(images/bg/wood.jpg); background-size:100%; background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
.LibrarySectsShelf_Book {
    border:1px #C90 solid;width:148px;height:23px; margin-bottom:1px;border-radius:3px 3px 3px 3px; font-size:10px; background-color: rgba(51,153,255,0.9); padding-left:2px; line-height:22px; color:rgba(255,255,255,1) !important; overflow: hidden;
}
.LibraryBooks {
    border:1px #CCC solid;width:502px; margin:2px; padding:1px;border-radius:2px 2px 2px 2px; font-size:10px; background-color: rgba(102,102,102,1); line-height:18px;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't want the 2nd content to appear beside the 1st content and so on instead of below it?

Comment: If you only need to support modern browsers, you can solve this with pure CSS, using text columns.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can achieve the output you want using only PHP,HTML,CSS solution which you are already using:

**PHP**

```
$i=1;
echo '<a class="LibSectOpen">
<span style="display:none" class="SectionName">'.$Section.'</span>
<div class="LibrarySects"><div class="LibrarySectsHeader">'.$Section.'</div>
<div class="LibrarySectsShelf"><div class="move_right">';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($log2)){ 
echo '<div class="LibrarySectsShelf_Book" style="background-color:'.$Color.'"
      title="Author: '.$row['bbookauthor'].'">'.$row['bbookname'].'</div>';
if($i%5==0)
{
    echo '</div><div class="move_right">';
}
$i++;
}
echo '</div></div></div></a>';
```

The above code uses `<div class="move_right"> ... </div>` to divide elements in group of 5 so as to display each group in a new column.

**CSS (.move_right)**

```
.move_right{
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

### [Fiddle of how the generated HTML's output will be](http://jsfiddle.net/2A7Hg/1/)

Comment: @Mr.Alien sry I am responding late but I have to tell you I didn't copy any part of your answer.I have **no proof** of it .I did saw the fiddle of ariel but I didnt even read a single word of your answer before I posted an answer myself since your answer is bit long.But after you posted the comment below my answer I read your answer and I have to say the CSS at the bottom of your answer is also good and I got to learn something new. +1

Comment: No issues, if you didn't copied than I will take my comment back :)

Answer (score 5):

I'll provide you with 2 solutions here, PHP and CSS, as @ariel has already contributed a jQuery solution, since I always like to be JS independent, and also it will save you, using a *third party script*, along with jQuery Library *(If you aren't using jQuery)*, I chosed PHP first, and than the CSS one which may be less compatible in terms of IE.

If you want to achieve that using PHP, you need to alter your loop and set a counter, which will break..

Assume that we are having an `array` of elements, and we want to set just like you need it..

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <ul>
        <?php
            $arr = array('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15');
            $counter = 0;
            foreach ($arr as $value) {
                if($counter%5==0 && $counter != 0){ echo "</ul><ul>";}
        ?>
            <li><?php echo $value; ?></li>
        <?php
                $counter++;
            }
        ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here, am using a counter variable which am incrementing at the end of the loop, the line over here `$counter%5==0` in `if` condition states that if the loop counter is divisible by 5, add `</ul><ul>`, hence, this will generate a group of `ul` which are *floated* to `left`.. consisting of 5 `li` each.

[**Demo**](http://phpfiddle.org/api/run/bt5-mzj) - [**Fiddle Code**](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/bt5-mzj)

**CSS**

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
    height: 150px;
    margin: 50px;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
}

ul {
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
}

ul li {
    height: 30px;
    width: 150px;
    background: tomato;
    border: 1px solid #515151;
}
```

Now as you said that *but after the number of contents is more than 5 the height becomes greater than that of the `div`* hence if you apply the same logic in your markup, it will force the `div` to start another column.

[**Demo**](http://phpfiddle.org/api/run/s3j-h8p) - [**Fiddle Code**](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/s3j-h8p)

```
<a class="LibSectOpen">
    <span style="display:none" class="SectionName"><?php $value; ?></span>
    <div class="LibrarySects"><div class="LibrarySectsHeader">Whatever</div>
        <div class="LibrarySectsShelf">
            <div class='inner_wrap'>
            <?php
                $arr = array('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15');
                $counter = 0;
                foreach ($arr as $value) {
                    if($counter%5==0 && $counter != 0){ echo "</div><div class='inner_wrap'>";}
            ?>
                <div class="LibrarySectsShelf_Book" title="Author:">Whatever <?php echo $value; ?></div>
            <?php
                    $counter++;
                }
            ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</a>
```

---

Doing the same with CSS, you can use `column-count` property, but as far as IE is concerned, it will make a mess.. though if you're interested in the solution, than here you go...

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mr_alien/59sRc/)

**HTML**

```
<ul>
   <li>1</li>
   <!-- More incremented li -->
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    column-count: 3;
}
```

[For Multi Column Support Reference](http://caniuse.com/multicolumn)

Answer (score 2):

My solution involves jQuery and the plugin [Columnizer](http://welcome.totheinter.net/columnizer-jquery-plugin/).

Here's the working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bortao/qGfsr/

The code is very simple:

```
$('.LibrarySectsShelf').columnize({
    width: 166,
    height: 150,
    doneFunc: function () {
        $('.LibrarySectsShelf_Book').removeClass('hidden');
    }
});
```

The only change in your css is this new class:

```
.hidden {
    visibility: hidden
}
```

Which should be added to every `LibrarySectsShelf_Book`. This is solely to prevent the flickering of the unorganized items. The class is removed when the columnization is complete.

Answer (score 2):

Easy.

```
.LibrarySectsShelf {writing-mode: vertical-lr;}
.LibrarySectsShelf_Book {display: inline-block;}
```

Works in every browser I tested, despite wiki pages claiming otherwise, and it's been around since IE8.

Comment: It shows me [Zero Support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/writing-mode)

Comment: @Mr.Alien Really? [This is what I see](http://i.imgur.com/jU635Qm.png). And, as I already stated, I tested the "?" browsers, and they support it - and I tested the "Not supported" browser, and it supports it.

Comment: `writing-mode: vertical-lr;` is *not* supported. But the example works fine *without it*.

Comment: Correction, it doesn't work. It keeps going left-to-right even with `writing-mode`set in IE8.

Answer (score 1):

## Solution using only CSS

The best way of doing this, is using CSS3 flex boxes like this:
[image: Example using CSS flexbox]

Here is how:

In the CSS add these 3 lines in `.LibrarySectsShelf{ ... }`

```
.LibrarySectsShelf {
   display: flex;               // to add
   flex-flow: column wrap;      // to add
   align-content: flex-start;   // to add

   ... // the rest of your code
}
```

and 1 line in `.LibrarySectsShelf_Book{ ... }`

```
.LibrarySectsShelf_Book{ 
   flex: 0 0 23px;

   ... // the rest of your code
}
```

## Cross browser support

Please note that since Flex box is a new feature in CSS3, you may have to add some browser prefixes like `-webkit-`, `-moz-` and `-ms-` to let it work properly in all major browsers.

Also note that the flex box wrap feature is only available in Firefox 28 and newer.

A working cross-browser example is available on http://jsfiddle.net/29Cmz/

## Why Flexbox

Because it is very flexible, it will fill up all the available space and you don't have to hardcode the number of rows in PHP/JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this may be helpful [HTML list elements top to bottom, then left to right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8290959/html-list-elements-top-to-bottom-then-left-to-right)
The jsfiddle shows that if you want to do this with css you can use css columns. Otherwise an answer below links to a js plugin to achieve this. Alternatively you could just do the positioning when you create the content in PHP if this is possible.

Comment: The fiddle on your link has the same problem as this one in this quetion

Comment: It's mentioned that this is not supported on all browsers.. the fiddle works for me on firefox 26

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you dont need the complete width of your main container.
Why don't you just add a fixed width to both categories and set them to `display:inline;` or `display:inline-block` (still messing these two up... sry).

If you want to determine it dynamically, you could check weather the height of your main container is sufficient for both categories. If this is not the case you could set the css attributes of both categories (I srsly hope for you they have the same css class ;) with

```
$('.your-class').css({'width':'250px', 'display':'inline'});
```

I think this should do the magic.

EDIT: Ahh sry. didint see your code... Never the less it should work this way ;)

Comment: As for dynamic, im not using json, im using php on the page.

Answer (score 0):

First of all . Don't put div in a tag .
Then you can find [array_chunk](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) php function .
So What you need to do.
It will  be better if you use [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) .
PDO fetch all will return `array`;

```
 <?php 
        $chunkSize = 5; // or any other value you need
        $chunks = array_chunk($result_array,$chunkSize);
        
           foreach($chunks as $links_array):?>
               <div class="move_right">
                  <?php foreach($links_array as $link):?>
                        <!-- your link code -->
                  <?php endforeach; ?>
               </div>
    <?php  endforeach ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code detects the end of the div and creates a new column using css.

```
var col = 1;
jQuery(
  function($)
  {
    $('#flux').bind('scroll', function()
          {
            if($(this).scrollTop() + 
               $(this).innerHeight()
               >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight)
                  {
                      $("#yourdiv").css("-moz-column-count",col);
                      $("#yourdiv").css("-webkit-column-count",col);
                      col++;
                  }
         })
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Tons of great answers here,  **I vote the javascript/CSS ONLY solution** because.

1) the PHP stays solely responsible for getting data to screen ( re use the same php logic for new presentations in the future )

2) The Javascript and CSS can be flexible to provide personalised markup arrangement per device, browser and view size

**DEMO** : http://jsfiddle.net/9Bc76/1/

---

**Markup** - Let PHP just generate the items and forget about presentation.

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="item">An Item</div>
   <div class="item"> An Item</div>
   <div class="item">An Item</div>
   ....
```

**Javascript to wrap the elements ( here is a hardcoded per 5 'items' )** - making use of the jquery selector and `wrapAll` method.

```
var items = $(".item");
for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i+=5) {
    items.slice(i, i+5).wrapAll('<div class="wrapper"></div>');
}
```

**CSS to layout**

```
.wrapper { display:inline-block; float:left; }
/* clear the float so the container keeps 'containing' */
.container:last-child:after { 
      clear:both; display:block;visibility:hidden; 
      height:0; content:"."; }
```

That's it.

---

More, If we need our 'wrap count' to be dynamic, we can do some calculation based on the height of the `.item` and the height of `.container` to get the desired 'wrap' count.

Lets say the container has a fixed height that is not allowed to grow;

```
.container { height: 300px; width: 100%; overflow: hidden; }
```

Javascript can find the 'wrap count interval' dynamically ( *find how may items fit in the container height* }

```
var containerheight = $(".container").height(),
itemheight = $(".item").height();

var wrapinterval = Math.floor(containerheight/itemheight);
```

Now we can use

```
var items = $(".item");
for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i+=wrapinterval) {
    items.slice(i, i+wrapinterval).wrapAll('<div class="wrapper"></div>');
}
```

**DEMO with dynamic wrap interval** - http://jsfiddle.net/2paNY/2/

---

APologies  to fellow SO'ers if this contains parts already answered in one way or another, I just got into typing away

Answer (score 0):

Just Copy and paste this piece of code and try at your end and use the logic.

```
<?php
for($i = 1; $i <= 20; $i++){
if($i % 5 == 1){
echo '<div style="float:left;">';
}
echo '<div class="LibrarySectsShelf_Book" style="background-color:'.$Color.'"
      title="Author: '.$row['bbookauthor'].'">'.$row['bbookname'].'</div>';

if($i % 5 == 0){
echo '</div>';
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Same again, why are you all duplicating the answers?